# How to use GreatSchools API module?

Tags: 7

I enabled the [GreatSchools module](https://www.drupal.org/project/great_schools) and entered the API KEY from greatschools in the configuration but there is no documentation on how to see the schools as content.

Can you point me to the right direction?

Comment: Belongs in the drupal.org issue queue as a support request.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Drupal API module making it easier to use The GreatSchools API / get data from GreatSchools. You have to write your own module (or enable the PHP module and write PHP directly in your nodes - not recommended) to use the functionality provided by the module. Currently it provides the following functions:

- great_schools_nearby_schools
- great_schools_browse_schools
- great_schools_browse_districts
- great_schools_city_overview
- great_schools_nearby_cities
- great_schools_school_census_data
- great_schools_school_profile
- great_schools_school_search
- great_schools_school_test_scores
- great_schools_school_reviews

Good luck!

PS! I have never used this module myself.